# Specify table/column/cell widths in Outlook email from SAS

Tags: email, outlook, sas, ods

Is it possible to specify table/column/cell widths of a HTML table in Outlook using proc print?

I've tried defining templates and specifying via styles and the tagattr option.
Using the style= option on proc print.

Comment: Is the issue Outlook, or `proc print`?  IE do you know how to do it for a regular HTML file, just not for one intended to send to Outlook?

Comment: The issue appears to be outlook.  I've viewed the HTML source of the emails I'm generating, and despite the HTML tags and styles I've tried all supposedly being supported by that version of the outlook/word rendering engine, nothing works.  Just to clarify, I'm viewing the HTML source from within outlook.  I'm assuming outlook isn't modifying the 'source' in any way before presenting it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting emails for certain clients (Outlook, gmail, yahoo etc) is a job role all in itself.  There are books written on the subject, but a primer can be found [here](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/unmasking-html-emails).  The short answer is that no, it is not possible using `proc print`..  instead you are going to have to generate very specific HTML and CSS in order to get around the rules applied by the Outlook rendering engine.

For instance, Outlook will strip all of your default styles - they have to be applied as attribute specific styles (eg `<table style="width:300px">`) .

Further tips [here](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/prepare-emails-outlook-tricks#sm.00016uxvyu98bfnrw5d1caw29157b), but many can be found with a keyword search on "outlook email styles"..

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.  I just spent 4 hours trying every permutation of every option available.